# Translate predicate calculus statement into Prolog

Tags: prolog, computer-science, predicate

can we translate the following logic from

```
empty_class(C) ← ¬∃X(takes(X, C)) .
```

to

```
empty_class(C):-takes(not(X),C)
```

?
my take is ¬∃X = ∀X
Can anyone help me with this logic, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. It translates as

```
empty_class(C) :- not( takes( X, C) ).
```

`not` is deprecated, so we write this as

```
empty_class(C) :- \+ takes( _, C) .
```

This is already an existential.